# Best approach to set secret key values for multiple products and different environments for each product

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Currently my company is moving all our products Azure and as part of migration we are using Azure key vault for storing secret keys. We have around 10 to 15 products and for each product we use review, integration, staging and production environment.

I don't see an option to configure secrets to different environment and products as in Vault Enterprise which we currently use. I am here to ask a best approach to configure secret keys for different products and corresponding environments in Azure key vault. So that it will easy to manage the secrets on Azure key vault.

Note: We do have around 5 to 10 keys for each environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had good experiences with using dedicated KeyVaults for each environment. The main advantage of using a "KeyVault per Stage" approach is that you can have the same key name in every KeyVault. This really saves you from a lot of complexity when consuming the values later on. Also, if you decide to create a new environment or drop an existing one, you don't have to worry about affecting other environments.

We usually also extend this to also create a dedicated KeyVault per product. As such, you will have "only what you need" and it is quite transparent. If you have a lot of "shared values", you could also create "common" KeyVaults instead.

If you use Azure Pipelines, it can be very nice to link the KeyVaults to a stage in the pipeline. This also works with YAML pipelines. Again, having the same secret name in each environment helps a lot in this case, since each environment can be identical.

Sidenote: With Azure Pipelines, you could also store some secrets as "secret variables". Probably not enough for your case, but I wanted to make sure you know.

[image: link to variable groups]

Answer (score 1):

You must use variables in the pipeline that will contain values from the key vault, then, just set the variables to the related product / environment.

For more info:

https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/

https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/06/26/PassingVariablesfromStagetoStage/

Comment: As per this I need to add all the secret keys across different products and environments to same key vault and use the corresponding variables in pipeline. This approach will create confusion and difficult to manage variables later.

Comment: One solution will be to have separate resource group for each product and separate key vault for each environment in one resource group. I am not sure if this is a good approach.

Comment: it's up to you. I've posted how to achieve what you need.